# Multiple urls to single host with port mapping?

Tags: ip

When one registers a url with a dns registrar can they include port mapping to the host computer?

www.myurl1.com myip:80
www.myurl2.com myip:81

Basically can one map several urls to the same host computer using port 80 as seen from the outside(so one doesn't have to do www.myurl2.com:81)?

Answer (score 2):

You can add Virtual Hosts to your webs-servers conf file.  Just have your dns registrar point all your domains to the same IP# port :80 and the web-server will do the rest.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/

Apache httpd.conf example:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/myurl1.com/"
   ServerName myurl1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/myurl1.com/"
   ServerName myurl2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Nginx - See http://wiki.nginx.org/ServerBlockExample